# What do "ACard AHCI SATA low-level driver" meaning? What is "ACard"?

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I run on Debian Stretch,my linux-kernel version is `4.14.13`
Is this module never used(real loaded) in initramfs for desktop PC?
The context is for initramfs and I have a very slow usb storage device(3.7M vmlinuz take about 60s to loaded),If it never use in desktop PC,I want remove it from my initramfs.
Note simple test on my machine is not work bacause I want my initramfs work in most desktop PC.

```
$ sudo modinfo acard-ahci 
filename:       /lib/modules/4.14.13/kernel/drivers/ata/acard-ahci.ko
version:        1.0
license:        GPL
description:    ACard AHCI SATA low-level driver
author:         Jeff Garzik
srcversion:     54FB6F53A7A13A663E876F4
alias:          pci:v00001191d0000000Dsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        libahci,libata
intree:         Y
name:           acard_ahci
vermagic:       4.14.13 SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
$
```

Comment: the manufacturer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ACard is the manufacturer of the ATP 8620 which this driver supports. The kernel module is automatically loaded on systems which require it.

Determining how likely your initramfs is to encounter one is rather difficult. I get the impression the ACard controller wasn’t particularly popular, but I wouldn’t go as far as saying it was never used in a desktop PC. However it seems safe to say you won’t find one in a PC built in the last four or five years.

Comment: Thank you for pay attention to this question, I'm sorry for my unclear at previous versions, I already reword my question. the context is for initramfs and very slow USB storage device to load my initramfs. more details see my question edit.